# using Newtonsoft.Json: System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a public definition for

Tags: json.net

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' because 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
 dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);    
                     foreach (var data in dyn.data)
                     {
                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I done this:
Add Microsoft.CSharp.dll please